# Add (prepend) line to file, if parameter is not already existing

Tags: bash, shell

I need to prepend an parameter `external_url 'https://ci.$domain.com'` to the file `/opt/gitlab/config/gitlab.rb`.

This is how I would start with that:

```
sed -i -e "external_url 'https://ci.$domain.de'" -e "wq" /opt/gitlab/config/gitlab.rb
```

But I also need to check if the parameter is not already existing in the file to avoid multiple entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With *grep* + *sed* and *shell* logical `||` operator:

```
p="external_url 'https://ci.$domain.com'"
grep "$p" /opt/gitlab/config/gitlab.rb || sed -i "1i $p" /opt/gitlab/config/gitlab.rb
```

Comment: @Inian, see my update

Comment: Is there a smart way to run this for multiple parameters? As a JS developer I would use an array and do a forEach loop. Is there something similar in shell?

Comment: @user3142695, shell also has its `for` loop. I would put all params in a file, then iterate through the lines

Answer (score 0):

To check if the link exists in the file:

```
link="external_url 'https://ci.$domain.de'"

if grep -Fxq "$link"  /opt/gitlab/config/gitlab.rb ; then
    echo $link already exists
else
    <command to insert the link>
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a one-liner

```
$ for i in ${arrayName[@]}; do if grep "$i" /opt/gitlab/config/gitlab.rb > /dev/null; then continue; else sed -i '1i $i' /opt/gitlab/config/gitlab.rb; fi; done
```